# Programmatically attaching a VHD to a remote Hyper-V VM

Tags: c#, hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, vhd

Using Hyper-V Manager, I can connect to a remote VM host, go to the settings of a VM, and add an existing .VHD file as a new hard disk. If the VM host is running Server 2008 R2, and the disk is being attached to a SCSI controller, I can even do this while the VM is running (see [What's new in Hyper-V R2](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-r2.aspx)).

Doing this manually, everything works great. The trouble is, now I want to automate it so I can attach different VHDs on-the-fly during some automated tests.

I already have C# code that connects to the remote VM host over WMI and starts/stops VMs by calling [RequestStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723874(VS.85).aspx), and I'd like to extend it to be able to say "here's the path to a VHD, attach it as a SCSI drive to this VM". But looking at the [list of WMI virtualization classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136992(VS.85).aspx), I can't figure out how to do this.

The closest I've found is the [Mount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136811(VS.85).aspx) method of [Msvm_ImageManagementService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136845(VS.85).aspx), but this appears to mount a VHD inside the current OS, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to add *synthetic disk* (ResourceType.**Disk**, ResourceSubType.**DiskSynthetic**) using Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService.AddVirtualSystemResources. Parent = SCSI controller's WMI path.

```
ManagementObject synthetic = Utilities.GetResourceAllocationSettingData(scope,
    ResourceType.Disk, ResourceSubType.DiskSynthetic);
synthetic["Parent"] = <ideControllerPath>; //or SCSI controller path (WMI path)
synthetic["Address"] = <diskDriveAddress>; //0 or 1 for IDE
string[] RASDs = new string[1];
RASDs[0] = synthetic.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
```

Then to attach *virtual hard disk* (ResourceType.**StorageExtent**, ResourceSubType.**VHD**) using Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService.AddVirtualSystemResources. Parent = Synthetic disk's WMI path, **Connection** = *.vhd file path.

```
ManagementObject hardDisk = Utilities.GetResourceAllocationSettingData(scope,  
    ResourceType.StorageExtent, ResourceSubType.VHD);
hardDisk["Parent"] = <syntheticPath>; //WMI path
string[] connection = { <vhdPath> }; //Path to *.vhd file
hardDisk["Connection"] = connection;
string[] RASDs = new string[1];
RASDs[0] = hardDisk.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
```

Use [Common Utilities for the Virtualization Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723869(VS.85).aspx) and [WMI Explorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at http://hypervlib.codeplex.com for an example.