# How do I programatically add NICs to a Hyper-V VM?

Tags: wmi, hyper-v, wmic

I have a large number of virtualized servers.  To each of them, I would like to add a single additional virtual NIC.  Can anyone provide some pointers on how to script this?  I've looked at [Programmatically attaching a VHD to a remote Hyper-V VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210288/programmatically-attaching-a-vhd-to-a-remote-hyper-v-vm) but I'm not that conversant in C#.

Also, can I do this without having to halt the VM?  I realize that the guest OS may need to be rebooted to use the new NIC, but I'm not worried about that yet.  I just want to "hot plug" the new NICs.

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspbind  ; http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspscrub  - will any of these help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do it in C#, you can use the Hyper-V PowerShell cmdlet: **Add-VMNetworkAdapter**

For basic documentation on the cmdlet, see:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848564.aspx

Example usage:

> Add-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName **YourVMNameHere** -SwitchName **YourVirtualSwitchNameHere**

If you do need to do this in C# you can either just add a reference reference the PowerShell Hyper-V library.

If you don't want PowerShell you'll need to use the Hyper-V WMI provider. Be careful with this one as there are significant differences between the V1 and V2 provides. V1 is basically for 2008 and V2 for 2012 and 2012 R2. This requires significantly more effort.

For V2 WMI Api example adding a network card, see:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2013/07/15/adding-a-network-adapter-to-a-vm-using-the-hyper-v-wmi-v2-namespace.aspx

This last one, though written in PowerShell, can be backported to pure C# WMI code. The objects would be the same.